# Child Divider Is Not Visible in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have the Following View in my XML. I am setting the childDivider to a color. But my child divider is not visible.

```
<ExpandableListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/contacts_first_level_list_view"
            android:childDivider="@color/text_color_grey_directives"
            android:dividerHeight="@dimen/d1"/>
```

Please let me know if i have to do any thing other than this to see the divider only between Childs(No Divider between parents). Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

I just ran in to this problem and finally found the answer. Check to see that isChildSelectable() is set to return true. (I know this is old but it may help someone.)